# Convert data.frame to xts object and preserve types

Tags: r, xts, zoo

Is there a way to create an xts object from a data.frame and preserve data type?  My numerics are being converted to character.  This post from 2009 suggests merging columns into an existing xts:
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/as-xts-convert-all-my-numeric-data-to-character-td975564.html

It wasn't clear whether that is the ONLY way to do this.  Seems a bit of a hack and cumbersome for large data frames.  I would think out-of-the-box xts would respect the datatypes.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of the data.frame object you're trying to convert?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't.  xts/zoo objects are a matrix with an index attribute and you can't mix types in a matrix.

We've considered creating an xts-data.frame class but a primary concern of xts is speed and memory efficiency.  data.frames are not speed and memory efficient, so this hasn't been a priority.

Comment: so an input data.frame is simply converted to a matrix?  Perhaps I'm missing the the point of xts (I'm new to this object).  When I think of timeseries data I think of a table with the following columns: Date,Characteristic1,Characteristic2,...   where Date is date/time and Characteristic1... is whatever you are measuring - numeric or categorical or missing.

Comment: The "Date" of an xts object is not a column in the matrix, it's an attribute attached to it.  All your "Characteristics" must be the same type.

Comment: per your comment about the xts-data.frame, I think its a great idea.  If the user demands a data.frame then he/she should accept the tax of speed and memory.  Personally, the speed/memory is not an issue for the types of problems I work on - I use data.frame all over the place because its a more natural representation of the type of data I deal with.  I would happily pay a speed/memory tax for all the benefits that xts/zoo provides.

Comment: I think it's a good idea too, but I don't need it... so there's little incentive for me to write it. ;-)

Comment: totally understand =)  Anyways, xts is still useful in the data.frame case - perhaps I can't create single xts objects, but where I need an xts/zoo helper function (like na.approx) I can always subset my data frame to numerics

Comment: @SFun28, `na.approx` does not make sense for non-numeric data and the same goes for many other time series operations.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, my solution was to not include the time column when specifying the data object.  As long as all the other columns are of the same type, there should be no problems.

i.e.

data <- xts(data[,2:6], order.by = data$time, unique = FALSE, tzone = "")

(data$time is the first column and is POSIXct so I'm excluding it.  everything else is numeric)